# Replacing two regexes in one pass

Tags: regex

I want to make two regex replacements on one string, i.e. in Java terms

```
myString.replaceAll(pattern1, replacement1).replaceAll(pattern2, replacement2);
```

However, suppose that `myString` may be very long, so it would be desirable to avoid doing two passes over it. Can this be done in single pass?

```
String pattern = ...;
String replacement = ...;
myString.replaceAll(pattern, replacement);
```

The obvious candidate for `pattern` is `pattern1 + "|" + pattern2`, but then I can't see how to write `replacement`.

To simplify, let's assume that matches of `pattern1` and `pattern2` can't intersect, and that `replacement1` doesn't introduce any new matches of `pattern2`.

Comment: Is doing the replacement in two passes _actually_ a performance problem? This smells like premature optimization to me.

Comment: It's more of a question which I thought was interesting. My situation is simple enough that 1) I can avoid it; 2) it wouldn't be a major problem anyway.

Comment: Just because you *can* do it doesn't mean it's a good idea.  You're probably going to be adding complexity where it is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to maintain a hash that maps strings to their replacements.  Compose a match that matches any of the keys, and pass the matched key to the replacement portion. Have the replacement portion than pull in the value.

In Perl, that would merely be:

```
my @keys = keys %hash;
my $alt = '\b(' . join("|", @keys) . ')\b';
s/($alt)/$hash{$1}/g;
```

The equivalent Java solution would — like everything — be significantly longer, but the same approach would work.

Ordering issue do arise if one string is a starting substring of another.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the fact, which programming language you use, you can use a callback as replacement and use a RegExp which matches on both things and then you'll have an if statement in the callback function which checks with regexp matched and replace it with the appropriate replacement.

Comment: Voted up, but not available in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike virtually every other regex flavor out there, Java's doesn't support callbacks.  However, it does expose some lower-level API calls that let you implement them yourself.  Here's a post that shows how to do it:

[Java Regex Replace with Capturing Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277990/java-regex-replace-with-capturing-group/1282099#1282099)

As you indicated, you would need to combine the patterns into one, but you also need to isolate each pattern in its own capturing group, like so:

```
String bigPattern = "(" + pattern1 + ")|(" + pattern2 + ")";
```

(If the patterns already contain capturing groups, this will change the numbering scheme; you'll have to adjust any backreferences.  I'll assume there are no capturing groups except the ones you just created.)

Then, within the `replacement()` method, you determine which group actually matched, and choose the replacement text accordingly:

```
public String replacement()
{
  if (group(1) != null)
  {
    return replacement1;
  }
  else if (group(2) != null)
  {
    return replacement2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @levu said, it depends on the programming language. In Ruby, you could do something like this:

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > s
 => "hello world" 
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > s.gsub(/(hello|world)/) {|match| match == 'hello' ? 'hi there!' : 'universe!' }
 => "hi there! universe!"
```

When gsub sees either "hello" or "world" in the String s, it sends that value to the block in the variable called match. The block replaces "hello" with "hi there!", and replaces any other value with "universe!"