# How do you capture and reuse a match with Java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to remember the correct notation for doing find-replace regex matches in Java.

Say I have the string

```
    String s = "My name is ''Eric'' and I have a bee called ''Eric'' 
and a fish called ''Wanda''."
```

I want to do something like the following:

```
s.replaceAll("\'\'$$\'\'", "$$");
```

To give: **My name is Eric and I have a bee called Eric and a fish called Wanda.**

But I know $$ isn't the correct notation to capture whatever is in the '' and use it to replace the found match.

What's the particular notation I'm looking for here?

Thanks in advance.

-Dave.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
s.replaceAll("\'\'(.*?)\'\'", "$1");
```

Comment: Are you sure the \ syntax works? regular-expressions.info says Java only supports $ syntax for back-references.

Comment: Im not guaranteeing anything as i haven't tried it myself. But the `Pattern` Javadoc states `\n   Whatever the nth  capturing group matched`

Comment: Yeah, it's not \\1 or \1. I'll run some tests and refer to the below.

Comment: .replaceAll("\'\'(.*?)\'\'", "$1") gives me what I wanted. Cheers.