# regex to split a string containing tags by spaces but not breaking the tags in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to form a regex that functions as mentioned below:

String `killing of <span class="abc">cats</span>, hi <span class="xyz">dogs</span>,`

Splits into :

```
1. killing
2. of
3. <span class="abc">cats</span>,
4. hi
5. <span class="xyz">dogs</span>,
```

This regex `\\<.*?\\>|` splits it but tags are stripped and `,` after tags is a new string.

Comment: You **DO** want to read the answer with more than 4 000 upvotes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348

Comment: Maybe you should try to use "|[\\s,]+" instead of "| "

Comment: What do you expect (as a result) if you replace `cats` by `cats and mice` (e.g. child of `<span>` contains spaces). Or even nested spans?

Comment: @Andreas_D: I want everything from opening tag to the closing tag as one element in the split list. there will be no nested tags and it doesn't matter if there are spaces in between tags or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't help with a `split()`, but here's a solution with a sequential `find()`:

```
final String s =
    "killing of <span class=\"abc\">cats</span>, "
    + "hi <span class=\"xyz\">dogs</span>,";
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(
    "(<.*?>.*?</.*?>|\\w+)\\p{Punct}*").matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

**Output:**

```
killing
of
<span class="abc">cats</span>,
hi
<span class="xyz">dogs</span>,
```

Comment: @ Sean:thanks.. this is very close to what i need ..but it is splitting on hyphen and other punctuation marks and just want it to split on spaces. it should not split "non-govermental" into "non-" and "govermental" ..

Comment: @ Sean: didn't quite get it. please provide the regex!

Comment: @Surbhit a) something along the lines of `[\\w-]+` b) Kamahire's solution is better

Comment: @Sean:`"(<.*?>.*?</.*?>|\\w+)\\p{Punct}*\\w+"` this works!..thanks..Kamahire's regex using split is only giving tags and not the words. is there something i am missing ?

Comment: @Sean: yeah..your regex works pretty well for above example...i was just trying to modify so that it doesn't  find `non-govermental` as two separate words!

Comment: @Surbhit I'm sorry I thought IO was linking to Kamahire's answer. It turns out that it doesn't work after all.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] items = s.split("(?<=^|>)[^><]+?(?=<|$)");
```

I have tried this above. It works perfectly.

> UPDATE

```
    String str = "killing of <span class=\"abc\">cats</span>, hi <span class=\"xyz\">dogs</span>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|>)[^><]+?(?=<|$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

    int start = 0;
    int end =0;
    while(m.find()){
        start = m.start(0);
        end = m.end(0);
       String items[] = str.substring(start, end).split("\\s");
        for(String item:items){
                   System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kamahire I have edited your answer to make it more understandable. But +1, it works nicely

Comment: i tried it. This regex is only returning tags not the words before, after and in between tags!!

Comment: Does not work (with split) https://ideone.com/LzxvG - selects the tags only, like Surbhit already mentioned.

Comment: Please find the code for the same. I have update the answer with the code.

Comment: Grrr, I was linking to the wrong code all along, sorry. My bad, the others are right, this doesn't work. have to take back my +1

Answer (score 0):

Add a group arround the space and tag part and reference that group for the space in the replaceAll Call.

so your regex would look like (\\s)(\\<.*?\\>)?

then do a replaceAll on only the group 1, to be replaced with a line feeds. (remember group 0 is the whole match so 1 will only be the space). If there can be more than one space character add a plus after the (\\s).

For examples on how to replace using groups see the question: [Java Regex Replace with Capturing Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277157/java-regex-replace-with-capturing-group)

I will try and put a java example later. But I hope that this takes you in the right direction for now.