# string.replaceAll to replace occurrences

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to replace a string:

```
"abc.T.T.AT.T"
```

to a string with all single `T` to be replaced by `TOT` like

```
"abc.TOT.TOT.AT.TOT"
```

`strings.replaceAll` not working for this.

Comment: what do u mean singe T's? Is a single T considered a T between 2 dots, or a T that has no other T right next to it?

Comment: Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277157/java-regex-replace-with-capturing-group

Answer (score 8):

look around will solve your problem:

```
s.replaceAll("(?<=\\.|^)T(?=\\.|$)", "TOT");
```

if you do:

```
String s = "T.T.T.AT.T.fT.T.T";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=\\.|^)T(?=\\.|$)", "TOT"));
```

output would be:

```
TOT.TOT.TOT.AT.TOT.fT.TOT.TOT
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, what happens when the string has something like this:- `.(space)T(space)(space).`?

Comment: then the replace statement won't work. It is just based on OP's example. "dot" separated. well sure he didn't mention the definition of `single T`. at least my codes should work for his example.

Comment: An equivalent but super confusing regex is `(?<![^.])T(?![^.])`

Comment: @nhahtdh You had a typo, I think you meant `(?<![^.])T(?![^.])` negative of negative...:D

Comment: @Kent: Fixed it momentarily before you posted the comment. (The problem was forgetting the look-behind's `<`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for this task:

```
text.replaceAll("\\bT\\b", "TOT");
```

This will replace a "T" only if it is not preceded and not followed by another word character (means no other letter or digit before or ahead).

This will work for your example. But you should be aware, that this will match on all "T" with non word characters around. Replaced will be, e.g.:

- .T.
- %T%
- ,T,
- !T-

but not the "T" in:

- .This.
- .AT.
- .1T2.
- .T3

Comment: No letter or digits **or underscore**. So `T` in `%T%` will be replaced. I don't say it is wrong, just for OP's information.

Comment: @nhahtdh, thanks for your clarification. I added some examples to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
String input = "abc.T.T.AT.T";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input,".");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            String token = st.nextToken();
            if(token.equals("T")){
                token= token.replace("T", "TOT");
            }
            sb.append(token+".");
        }
            if(!(input.lastIndexOf(".")==input.length()-1))
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf("."));
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Hope this is what you require....

Comment: This will add an extra period to the end.

Comment: In the end just do ..sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf("."));

Comment: It won't work for `abt.T.T.`. I'm kind of allergic to solutions that only work for some inputs. (No downvote, but I was close to giving one.)

Comment: Sorry for missing this.. Let me add a check before deleting