# Can I combine a regex with a substring() in Java?

Tags: java, regex, substring

We're in the process of importing our documentation library to SharePoint, and I'm using a java program I wrote to build metadata for these documents. One of the things that I need to do is determine if a document has a cross referenced document. This condition is defined as having the phrase "see " in the document name. However, naming conventions are nonexistent, and all of the following variations exist:

```
document_see_other_document.doc
document_-_see_other_document.doc
document_(see_other_document).doc
document_[see_other_document].doc
document_{see_other_document}.doc
```

I have created a variable which defaults as such: `String xref = "no cross reference";` I would like to set this `String` to `"see_other_document"` in cases where there is a `see <other document>` substring in the filename.

My plan is to look for an instance of `see_`, use that as the start point of a substring, ending with the `.`, non-inclusive. But I want to ELIMINATE any special characters that may exist. In my cases above, I would like to return five instances of `other_document`, not `other_document)`, etc.

My thought was to pull the substring into a variable, then use a regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` and replace non-alphanumeric characters in that second string variable, but is there a better, more elegant way to skin this cat?

PSEUDOCODE:

```
if (filename.indexOf("see_">-1) {
    String tempFilename = fileName.substring(indexOf("see_")+4,indexOf("."-1));
    xref = tempFilename.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]","");
    } else {
    xref;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use regex capturing groups. See [this question][1] for how to do it.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277157/java-regex-replace-with-capturing-group

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex with optional parts. Following fragments shows how. (?:something ) is non capturing group:

```
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("_(?:\\-_)?(?:\\(|\\[|\\{)?see_([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)(?:\\)\\}|\\])?");

    for (String filename : new String[] {"document_see_other_document.doc", "document_-_see_other_document2.doc", 
            "document_(see_other_3document).doc", "document_[see_other_4document].doc", "document_{see_other_document5}.doc", "blacksee_other_document.doc"}){
        Matcher m= patt.matcher(filename);

        if (m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("negative");
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should use character classes to match those bracketing characters, i.e. `[(\\[{]?` and `[}\\])]?`.  Your way works okay, but look how much easier it is to read this way.

Answer (score 0):

As [Steve McConnell suggests](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) writing something in one line is not more elegant. I believe that your way of doing things is the most elegant one.

Let's suppose that you find a magical way of using a complex regular expression doing all these things in one line.

**Would the code be more readable then?**
Certainly not. Using complex regular expressions is far from easy reading. Nobody would understand what you want to do by reading a regular expression.

**Would the code be more maintainable?**
Certainly not. Changing a regular expression to do a slightly different match could be a very tedious task. The same with debugging.

**Would the code be faster?**
Maybe yes, maybe no. You would have to test it. Nevertheless, the performance difference is not your goal.

Therefore, I suppose your code is elegant enough and I would not suggerst to change it.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

In all of your exemplars, the junk characters occur just before and just after the message (`see_other_document`). And the message itself consists entirely of word characters (i.e., no punctuation and no whitespace).  Can we count on all those conditions?  If we can, this should put you right:

```
    String result = source.replaceAll(
         "(document_)[\\W_]*+(see_\\w++)[^\\w.]*+(\\.doc)",
         "$1$2$3");
```

The basic idea is if you don't want it, don't capture it.

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine actually, but you can try this:

```
if(filename.indexOf("see_">=0){
    String temp=filename.substring(filename.indexOf("see_")+4,filename.length()-4);
//                      if there exist '.' in "other_document"^
    xref=temp.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}0-9]","");
//                          ^here for unicode character
} else{
    xref;
}
```